# Following on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a basic following system in rails. It works fine in the rails console, but when I try to create one using a rest api, I am having problems. Any help would be very much appreciated. Here is my code:

To create  follower from rest api:

```
def create_follow
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  attributes = school_params
  respond_with @user.follow!(:school_id => attributes[:id].to_i)
end
```

School Params:

```
def school_params
  params.require(:school).permit(:id)
end
```

To follow:

```
def follow!(user)
  school_relationships.create!(user_id: user.id)
end
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for {:follow_id=>2}:Hash):
  app/models/user.rb:30:in `follow!'
  app/controllers/api/v1/user_controller.rb:23:in `create_follow'
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it's `follow_id` but not `id`.

```
def school_params
  params.require(:school).permit(:follow_id)
end
```

And in the action:

```
respond_with @user.follow!(:school_id => attributes[:follow_id].to_i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, your code expects a `user` object , but you are passing a Hash in

```
def follow!(user)
  school_relationships.create!(user_id: user.id)
end
```

it expects user object in `user_id: user.id`. But you are passing a hash in

`@user.follow!(:school_id => attributes[:id].to_i)`

so update your `follow!` method accordingly